# ¿Cómo instalar dependencias en la línea de comandos para una aplicación que desea implementar en Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

Al intentar implementar [mi aplicación](https://github.com/antoinecomp/myflaskapp/) en Heroku tuve el siguiente error

```
           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'    
           ----------------------------------------   
       Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sgi6cwh2/ssh-import-id/

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.   
 !     Push failed
```

Ya sabía que [tenía problemas con las dependencias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171230/c%C3%B3mo-administrar-los-errores-de-dependencia-al-implementar-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n), pero ese pertenecía al archivo requirements.txt
Así que todavía intenté instalarlo con heroku runn pip ins tall requests. Sin embargo, cualquier sea el command, obtuve

```
Item could not be created:

    Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later.
```

Traté de agregar `git+https://github.com/requests/requests.git` pero tampoco funciona.

Pero la compilación se realiza cuando elimina todo en los [requirements.txt](https://github.com/antoinecomp/myflaskapp/blob/master/requirements.txt) después de vaciar todos `requirements.txt` de forma remota. Me inspiré en la [respuesta de maxko87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021874/heroku-gunicorn-not-working-bash-gunicorn-command-not-found). Pero de repente, supongo que no tenemos dependencia, ni siquiera `gunicorn`

Me pregunto si la razón no es que el archivo contenga dependencias C no compatibles que no proporcionan ruedas "manylinux" no se instalarán en Heroku. Y si no tengo que usar miniconda [como dicen en la documentación](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps).

Aquí está mi contenido del archivo requirements.txt que hice de un congelamiento. Creo que es limpiable pero no sé cómo.

```
gunicorn==19.0.0
absl-py==0.1.11
alabaster==0.7.10
git+https://github.com/apixu/apixu-python.git
APScheduler==3.5.1
#apturl==0.5.2
astor==0.6.2
attrs==18.1.0
Automat==0.6.0
Babel==2.5.3
backports.csv==1.0.5
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bleach==1.5.0
blinker==1.3
boto==2.48.0
boto3==1.6.6
botocore==1.9.6
#Brlapi==0.6.4
bz2file==0.98
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==2.3.0
checkbox-support==0.22
click==6.7
cloudpickle==0.5.2
coloredlogs==10.0
#command-not-found==0.3
ConfigArgParse==0.13.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==1.2.3
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==1.31.2
cytoolz==0.8.2
decorator==4.2.1
#defer==1.0.6
dill==0.2.7.1
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.14
elasticsearch==6.2.0
elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0
#en-core-web-sm==2.0.0
entrypoints==0.2.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fakeredis==0.10.3
fbmessenger==4.3.1
feedparser==5.1.3
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
future==0.16.0
gast==0.2.0
gensim==3.4.0
gevent==1.3.0
googletrans==2.2.0
graphviz==0.8.3
greenlet==0.4.13
grpcio==1.10.0
guacamole==0.9.2
h5py==2.7.1
html5lib==0.9999999
httplib2==0.9.1
humanfriendly==4.12.1
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.6
imagesize==1.0.0
incremental==17.5.0
ipaddress==1.0.22
ipykernel==4.8.0
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.1.1
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.4
jedi==0.11.1
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
joblib==0.11
jsonpickle==0.9.6
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.2
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras==2.1.5
kiwisolver==1.0.1
klein==17.10.0
#language-selector==0.1
#louis==2.6.4
lxml==3.5.0
Mako==1.0.3
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.2.0
mistune==0.8.3
#mitie==0.5.0
msgpack-numpy==0.4.1
msgpack-python==0.5.6
murmurhash==0.28.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
nbsphinx==0.3.3
networkx==2.1
nltk==3.2.5
notebook==5.4.0
numpy==1.14.3
oauthlib==1.0.3
#onboard==1.2.0
openpyxl==2.5.3
packaging==17.1
padme==1.1.1
pandas==0.21.0
pandoc==1.0.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.1.1
pathlib==1.0.1
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==3.1.2
pipenv==2018.5.18
plac==0.9.6
plainbox==0.25
ply==3.11
preshed==1.0.0
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
protobuf==3.5.2
ptyprocess==0.5
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycups==1.9.73
pycurl==7.43.0
Pygments==2.2.0
#pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pykwalify==1.6.0
pyparsing==2.0.3
#python-apt==1.1.0b1
python-dateutil==2.6.1
#python-debian==0.1.27
#python-systemd==231
python-telegram-bot==10.1.0
pytz==2017.3
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.4
qtconsole==4.3.1
rasa-core==0.8.6
rasa-nlu==0.11.5
redis==2.10.6
regex==2017.4.5
reportlab==3.3.0
requests==2.9.1
ruamel.yaml==0.15.37
s3transfer==0.1.13
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==1.0.0
seaborn==0.8.1
Send2Trash==1.4.2
#sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.14.0
six==1.11.0
sklearn==0.0
slackclient==1.2.1
smart-open==1.5.6
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
spacy==2.0.11
Sphinx==1.7.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.0.1
ssh-import-id==5.5
system-service==0.3
tensorboard==1.6.0
tensorflow==1.6.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3.1
thinc==6.10.2
toolz==0.9.0
torch==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.3
tqdm==4.23.3
traitlets==4.3.2
Twisted==18.4.0
typing==3.6.4
tzlocal==1.5.1
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.35
ujson==1.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unity-scope-calculator==0.1
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-colourlovers==0.1
unity-scope-devhelp==0.1
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-gdrive==0.7
unity-scope-manpages==0.1
unity-scope-openclipart==0.1
unity-scope-texdoc==0.1
unity-scope-tomboy==0.1
unity-scope-virtualbox==0.1
unity-scope-yelp==0.1
unity-scope-zotero==0.1
urllib3==1.22
usb-creator==0.3.0
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.47.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.1.3
wrapt==1.10.11
xdiagnose==3.8.4.1
xkit==0.0.0
xlrd==1.1.0
XlsxWriter==0.7.3
zope.interface==4.5.0
git+https://github.com/requests/requests.git
```

#### Actualización: después de agregar la creación del archivo pipe, la aplicación se implementó pero el mensaje de error de la aplicación

Aquí el Pipfile que agregué de un usuario llamado el consejo de Chris, soy nuevo en este tipo de archivo:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
```

That deployed my website but raised an application error message on it.
Here are my logs :

```
-----> Python app detected

 !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using python-3.5.2, which is unsupported).

 !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).

       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 11.8.2…
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile…
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 65.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v10
       https://moodbotbot.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Ahora estoy tratando de ver si no debería agregar paquetes en este Pipfile

#### Actualizacion

Con poca información con los registros, traté de encontrar herramientas que me dieran más, incluida la creación de un Pipefile para Travis que crea un archivo .lock que plantea un nuevo problema aqui.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"

[packages]
requests = { extras = ['socks'] }

[requires]
python_version = "3.6.5"
```

Lo que me da ahora:

```
-----> Installing pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pipenv-to-pip", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pipenv-to-pip", line 11, in main
    lockfile = json.load(f)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Todo esto es muy nuevo para mí. Si sabes cómo volver a la pista, estaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando corres `heroku run` lo que ocurre es que heroku genera una instancia de tu aplicación que tiene una copia de tu repo con acceso shell, pero no es la aplicación web. De manera que si hicieras `heroku run touch hola.txt` ese `hola.txt` no estaría en realidad accesible desde la web.

Para lo que necesitas, tienes que añadir el buildpack de python:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Esto también puedes hacerlo desde el panel `settings` de tu aplicación en el dashboard de heroku.

Cuando tienes ese buildpack instalado, al deployar la aplicación ocurren los siguientes pasos:

- se instala un virtualenv (creo que usa Pipenv)
- activa el virtualenv
- instala pip
- instala los paquetes contenidos en tu `requirements.txt` o en tu `Pipfile` (buscará en ese orden) en el virtualenv
- corre el comando que hayas puesto en el archivo `Procfile`

El contenido de tu `Procfile` puede ser, por ejemplo

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT mi_app.wsgi
```

o bien

```
web: gunicorn -c python:mi_app:config  mi_app.main:app
```

o simplemente llamar a una tarea de un Makefile si te acomoda ese approach. (Yo lo uso así y llamo a gunicorn en el makefile)

```
web: make start
```

**La otra manera**

Si te manejas bien con docker, puedes usar una instancia de tipo docker en vez de una instancia heroku-16 o cedar-14 que son las que te asigna por defecto al crear tu app. Cuando haces eso, puedes definir el build a tu gusto en tu mismo dockerfile y alojar la imagen en el repo que heroku tiene para eso, incluyendo la instalación de paquetes con `apt`. Pero de verdad, este método no lo domino y sólo lo menciono porque es una alternativa válida,

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, agrego heroku / python a través de `setting`, porque su terminal realmente no quiere funcionar, y No module named 'requests' y todavía tengo el primero que puse en la parte superior.

Comment: Añade el buildpack y luego vuelve a pushear la aplicación para que reintente el build. Si añades el buildpack y no ocurre un nuevo build no habrá ningún cambio. También puedes gatillar el build manualmente en otra parte del dashboard, me parece que en el log de actividad (no los logs de la aplicación)

Comment: Sí, lo siento, olvidé mencionar que hice un `deploy` en `Deploy`

Comment: Ha Volví a los requisitos iniciales sin los comentarios que eliminaban las dependencias que antes presentaban probemes y parece que di un paso adelante: "Deployed" a pesar del error de aplicación en [el sitio](https://moodbotbot.herokuapp.com/). Gracias por su ayuda, voy a ver los registros ahora

Comment: No había visto pero parece que la verdadera razón por la que funcionó es que eliminé los requisitos antes. Lo cual es muy extraño. ¡Especialmente como la aplicación, no creo que la aplicación pueda funcionar sin ellos!